# Facebook clever search through api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have two problems with Facebook.
First that from one account clever search works:
[image]

And from another with same settings and approved mobile number no:
[image]

How is it can be real?

And second problem: How can I use that clever search from API?
I tried:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/search?type=user&q=people+who+like+cars+and+live+in+moscow&access_token=token
```

And reply is empty. 
Please help me to understand that or I will become mad.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use the Graph Search with the API. You can only use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search) to search for a user by name, but nothing else. See the docs for more information, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/search?type=user&q=Maxim
```